# Knapsack variant: keep value above a threshold but minimize the costs

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, discrete-optimization

Suppose I have $N$ items with non-negative weights $w_1, \dots, w_N \geq 0$ and non-negative value $v_1, \dots, v_N \geq 0$.

The knapsack problem is to choose a subset $I \subseteq \{1,\dots,N\}$ such that

- $\sum_{i \in I} w_i \leq B$
- $\sum_{i \in I} v_i$ maximal,

where $B$ is an upper bound for the weight. In other words, I want to pack as much value into my knapsack as I can but keep the weight below $B$.

What about the following combinatorial problem: choose a subset $I \subseteq \{1,\dots,N\}$ such that

- $\sum_{i \in I} w_i$ minimal
- $\sum_{i \in I} v_i \geq C$,

where $C$ is a lower bound for the value. In other words, I want to pack as least weight into my knapsack as I can but keep the value above $C$.

Question: are these two problems equivalent? Can I easily reformulate one in terms of the other? Note that weights and values need to be non-negative.

Comment: What if you start off with a "full knapsack", and consider trying to remove some elements?

Comment: I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is,
\begin{align}
\max_s&\quad s^{T}v \\
s.t.&\quad s^Tw \leq B \\
&\quad s\in \{0,1\}^{N}
\end{align}
where $s = (s_1,s_2,\dots,s_N)$ is a vector that selects the $i$th item if $s_i=1$ and doesn't select the item if $s_i = 0$.

The second problem is,
\begin{align}
\min_\bar{s}&\quad \bar{s}^{T}\bar{w} \\
s.t.&\quad \bar{s}^T\bar{v} \geq C \\
&\quad \bar{s}\in \{0,1\}^{N}
\end{align}
which is equivalent to,
\begin{align}
\max_\bar{s}&\quad -\bar{s}^{T}\bar{w} \\
s.t.&\quad -\bar{s}^T\bar{v} \leq -C \\
&\quad \bar{s}\in \{0,1\}^{N}
\end{align}

Therefore, the second problem can be formulated as a knapsack problem by setting, $-\bar{w} = v$, $-\bar{v} = w$ and $-C = B$.